# While loops in an if statement

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I have to display "Greater than 10" four times if a user enters in a number greater than 10 and "Less than 10" seven times, if the user enters a number less than 10. I'm able to get the "Less than 10" to display but I'm stumped as to what to do next.

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num;
    int i = 0;

    System.out.print("Please enter a number: ");
    num = sc.nextInt();

    if(num < 10)
    {
        while(i < 7)
        {
            System.out.println("Less than 10");
            i++;
        }
    }
```

I know I'm screwing up somewhere with the counter variable 'i' but I've been looking at this so long, my brain is fried. Anyone able to assist with this issue? Also, yes. I'm restricted to if statements and while loops.

Comment: set i back to 0, then make a duplicate if/while statement (this time if num > 10)

Comment: @user56029283888 You don't need to reset `i` because it wont iterate `i` unless `num` is less than 10

Comment: Move the declaration of i (i.e. int i = 0) into the if block. That way its limited to the scope of that block. Small point, but better practice.

Comment: @FelixMarcus Yes. If else and while loops only.

Comment: And what do you have to output if it is exactly 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use another "if" (since you prefer using only an if) structure for greater than 10. For a given input it will enter just one of the if structures. (You also have an option to use "else if")

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num;
    int i = 0;

    System.out.print("Please enter a number: ");
    num = sc.nextInt();

    if(num < 10)
    {
        while(i < 7)
        {
            System.out.println("Less than 10");
            i++;
        }
    }

    if(num>10)
    {
        while(i < 4)
        {
            System.out.println("greater than 10");
            i++;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This is exactly what works. I changed the last if statement to an else. I was erroneously making the counter greater than 4! Don't judge me like I said, my brain is fried.

Answer (score 2):

You're going to repeat the process you did for "less than" but for "greater than". Make another if statement, check if it is greater than 10, then proceed into the while loop for 4 iterations.

There is no need to reset `i` because it wouldn't have iterated if the input is greater than 10.

Comment: And think about what happens when `num==10`

Comment: @GameDroids Yes, the program will do nothing if `num == 10`. OP never specified what should occur.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an else statement:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   int num;
   int i = 0;

   System.out.print("Please enter a number: ");
   num = sc.nextInt();

   if(num < 10)
   {
       while(i < 7)
       {
           System.out.println("Less than 10");
           i++;
       }
   }
   else if(num > 10)
   {
       while(i < 4)
       {
           System.out.println("Less than 10");
           i++;
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (num < 10)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  { 
      System.out.println("Less than 10");
  }
}
else if (num > 10)

{
  for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) 
  {
      System.out.println("More then 10");
  }
}
```

now translate :

```
for (int i=0; i<N; i++) { blabla; }
```

into

```
{ int i=0; while (i<N) { blabla; i++ } }
```

Comment: OP stated he could only use if, else, and while statements. Can't use for loops.

Comment: That's useful and easier to read but unfortunately, I'm restricted to if else statements and while loops here. Thanks anyway.

Comment: if you put in 10, then it will say "greater than 10"

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to count down target iterations because it makes the code a little easier than trying to remember why something is < 7 or < 4.

```
if(num < 10)
{
    i = 7;

    while(i > 0)
    {
        System.out.println("Less than 10");
        i--;
    }
}
else if( num > 10)
{
    i = 4;

    while( i > 0 )
    {
        System.out.println("Greater than 10");
        i--;
    }
}
```

Comment: if you put in 10, then it will say "greater than 10"

Answer (score 0):

you have to add an else if statement in order to catch the second condition

```
   if(num < 10){
      while(i < 7){
        System.out.println("Less than 10");
        i++;
      }
   }else /*if(num >= 10)*/{ // the commented section is optional
      if(num > 10){
        while(i < 4){
          System.out.println("Greater than 10");
          i++;
        }
      }


   }
```

Comment: if you put in 10, then it will say "greater than 10"

Comment: Somehow we have to handle the condition the given number is equal to 10. The question does not make clear what happens in this condition. Can you tell me which behaviour we have to follow in this situation? I personally can not :)

Comment: looking at the code and having some understanding on the domain of integers i know that 10 is not greater than 10 at least, so my assumption would be to not print anything, or print "Equal to 10" (this was not part of the task though)